# R: sum values in rows when name is the same

Tags: r, for-loop, duplicates

I have a data frame in R where I want to sum values from rows that share a name and record the fake name for each of those rows. Can anyone think of an efficient way to do this? I wrote a for-loop (copied below), but it is extremely inefficient on the large dataset.

Thanks in advance!

A few things are given in this dataset: (1) no more than 2 sites will share a name and (2) the two sites will always be next in consecutive rows. I'm also open to non-R solutions, although I'm not as familiar with other frameworks.

Example initial data:

```
name, fake_name, value1, value2, value3
siteX, siteX, 4, 2, 0.5
siteX, siteX2, 1, 4, 0.2
siteY, siteY, 2, 1, 0.4
siteZ, siteZ, 8, 3, 0.2
```

Transformed to:

```
name, value1, value2, value3, fake_name, dup_fake_name
siteX, 5, 6, 0.7, siteX, siteX2
siteY, 2, 1, 0.4, siteY, NA
siteZ, 8, 3, 0.2, siteZ, NA
```

For-loop version:

```
data[,c(1,3:5,2)] -> d2; d2$dup_fake_name <- NA
for (i in 1:(nrow(data)-1) {
  if (data$name[i] == data$name[i+1]) {
    data$value[i] <- data$value[i] + data$value[i+1]
    data$dup_fake_name[i] <- data$fake_name[i+1]
}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'name', get the `sum` of 'value' column, `dcast` the 'fake_name' to wide format and join `on` the 'name' column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = name, .SDcols = value1:value3
       ][dcast(df1, name~ paste0("fake_name", rowid(name)), value.var = 'fake_name'), 
          on = .(name)]
#    name value1 value2 value3 fake_name1 fake_name2
#1: siteX      5      6    0.7      siteX     siteX2
#2: siteY      2      1    0.4      siteY         NA
#3: siteZ      8      3    0.2      siteZ         NA
```

Answer (score 4):

Provided you don't care about the last two columns in your transformed data, you can `aggregate` entries

```
 df <- structure(list(
     name = c("siteX", "siteX", "siteY", "siteZ"),
     fake_name = c("siteX", "siteX2", "siteY", "siteZ"), 
     value1 = c(4L, 1L, 2L, 8L), 
     value2 = c(2L, 4L, 1L, 3L), 
     value3 = c(0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2)), 
     .Names = c("name", "fake_name", "value1", "value2", "value3"), 
     class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

 df.agg <- aggregate(cbind(value1, value2, value3) ~ name, data = df, FUN = sum);
 #name value1 value2 value3
 #1 siteX      5      6    0.7
 #2 siteY      2      1    0.4
 #3 siteZ      8      3    0.2
```

To add the IDs is a bit more (ugly) work:

```
# Split based on df$name
ID <- lapply(split(df, df$name), function(x) x$fake_name)

# Pad with NA's to have the same number of columns 
ID <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(ID, function(x) {
    if (length(x) < max(sapply(ID, length))) {
        x <- c(x, rep(NA, max(sapply(ID, length)) - length(x)))
    }
    return(x); 
}))
colnames(ID) <- paste("fake_name_", 1:ncol(ID), sep = "");

# Add ID columns to df.agg
df.agg <- cbind.data.frame(df.agg, ID);
df.agg;
#  name value1 value2 value3 fake_name_1 fake_name_2
#1 siteX      5      6    0.7       siteX      siteX2
#2 siteY      2      1    0.4       siteY        <NA>
#3 siteZ      8      3    0.2       siteZ        <NA>
```

Comment: This seems just about perfect, except I can't figure out what `tmp` refers to

Comment: Ah my apologies. `ID` used to be called `tmp` when I was trying to put together the example. I've corrected my code.

Comment: No worries, glad it worked. If this answer your question, please accept the answer to close the question.

Comment: @jogo Yes, I've tried something similar before as well. It becomes "ugly" when you try to add the NAs to pad out the entries, as per OPs request; @akrun has a very neat (and much shorter) solution using `data.table`.

Answer (score 0):

The `fake_name` column can be split out if needed, but here is one version

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(name = c('siteX', 'siteX', 'siteY', 'siteZ'), 
           fake_name = c('siteX', 'siteX2', 'siteY', 'siteZ'),
           value1 = c(4,1,2,8),
           value2 = c(2,4,1,3),
           value3 = c(0.5,0.2,0.4,0.2))

df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(id = 1:n(),
         dup_fake_name = ifelse(id==2, fake_name, NA)) %>% 
  summarise(value1 = sum(value1),
            value2 = sum(value2),
            value3 = sum(value3),
            fake_name = toString(fake_name))
```